# Chrome Extension : make my extension to perform only when popup is clicked and display the results in the popup

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

As it clearly reads,

I want my popup to be the trigger for the extension to start. 
My extension basically can be performed completely in `background.html`. `Background.html` needs some info from the webpage, so use message passing for passing the required content from `contentscript.js` to `background.html`. This is becoming resource heavy to run on all the pages, So i want this extension to start only after the icon is clicked and display the information in the `popup.html` which i can directly pull from `background.html`.

Lemme know if i'm unclear.

Comment: You described how it should work but didn't say what is the question. Which part do you have trouble with?

Comment: @serg Hi Serg, i donno how to make the extension trigger when the popup is clicked. Need info about that.

Comment: * when popup is clicked(i.e when the browser icon is clicked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting when a popup is opened is pretty easy as the code inside it executes each time the popup is opened. So all you need to do is put a request to background page at the beginning of popup code.

Second part would be injecting content script on demand (into the current tab as I understand).

So the whole extension structure should be something like this:

**popup.html**

```
//this will run each time popup opens
chrome.extension.sendRequest("start", function(data) {
    //display data received from background page through content script
});
```

**background.html**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request == "start") {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "contentscript.js"}, function() {
                //content script is injected, send a request to it
                chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, "get_data", function(data){
                    //content script sent response back with data we need to display in popup
                    sendResponse(data);
                });
            });
        });
    }
}));
```

Something to keep in mind is that the popup might be already closed by the time it receives the data, so you might need to add some error handling.

Second issue would be avoiding injecting content script twice into the same page. This might be challenging, so I would suggest if your content script is small then just inject it into all pages (in manifest).